# Getting error when using Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 connection for import excel sheet

Tags: c#, asp.net, oledbconnection

i am new in asp.net

i am getting below error when i run my web application on IIS, i tried this code on both xp-64 bit and window-7

```
 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.
```

and when i run this on port like "http://localhost:1464/Default.aspx" it's running fine

i am using below code

```
OleDbCommand excelCommand = new OleDbCommand();
OleDbDataAdapter excelDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
string path = Server.MapPath(filename);
string excelConnStr = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;data source='" + path + "';Extended Properties='Excel 8.0; HDR=Yes; IMEX=1'";

OleDbConnection excelConn = new OleDbConnection(excelConnStr);
excelConn.Open();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to configure the application pool to 32 bit mode. check [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/b5a79958-5bce-4229-a69f-75589b6240a8)

Comment: can i do set connection string or something else according to 64 bit

Comment: no, as the link said: "both of Jet and ACE OLEDB provider only have x86 supported versions. An x64 process cannot load x86 component". If you run your application in 64bit, then you get this error.

Comment: i tried to set application pool to 32 bit mode
with this- but i didn't find "appcmd " on given path
To configure 32-bit mode for the server
Open a command prompt and run the following:
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:applicationPools -applicationPoolDefaults.enable32BitAppOnWin64:true

Comment: Below is how you do it from IIS7 manager:

Right click on the Application Pool and select “Advanced Settings…” or select the same from the Actions pane after selecting the Application pool
Change the “Enable 32-bit Applications” to True (if you want the application pool to spawn in a 32-bit mode)
Click OK

Comment: is it possible to do in iis6 ?

Comment: yes check http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/405f5bb5-87a3-43d2-8138-54b75db73aa1.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach it may help 
-> Fist copy your csv/excel file in application directory (create one folder under application directory and grant permission to ASP net user) 
-> then give this new path to connection string